# How do I resolve a question with conflicting apparently-correct answers?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I asked a [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7406/bicycle-on-shabbat) that has garnered conflicting answers, both citing sources.  It appears that the question is controversial and there isn't one agreed-upon answer.  If I'd received a response that summarized that controversy I could credit that, but since all the information is contained in other responses there's no clear reason for somebody to do that now other than to close the question.  I understand that I'm supposed to mark exactly one answer as correct.  How do I proceed?  Thanks.

Comment: Also see http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6/the-mark-as-accepted (possible duplicate)

Comment: I'd like to add two additional points: 1) There is no absolute requirement to mark an answer, you can leave it alone... 2) You can write an answer yourself that includes everything you think should be included. Like [what I did here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6508/sefira-nuschaos-differences)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67497/166155

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @yydl pointed out in the comments:

1. There is no absolute requirement to mark an answer, you can leave it alone...   (which sorta emphasizes that none of the answers are correct).
2. Better yet, you can write an answer yourself that includes everything you think should be included.
   It is okay to copy the other answers, as long as you're adding something (such as correlating the answers). This is perfectly legitimate, and not considered plagiarizing - just make sure you attribute to the original poster. (See what *I* did there, @yydl? ;) )
3. Also, if one of the answers is *almost* correct, but just missing one core detail, try leaving a comment. Often the poster will be glad to update accordingly. If that doesn't work, you can edit the answer yourself (as long as you don't change the core of the answer...)

Comment: Thanks.  Part of my concern is that I want to give the reputation credit where it's due.  If I compile an answer myself and get the credit for it that feels like theft, so then it comes down to deciding which responder should get all the credit because I can't split it.  Leaving comments to encourage them to edit sounds like the best approach.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, I think if you answer your own question you don't get reputation for it.

Comment: @Monica, as @msh210 says you dont get rep for your accepting your own answer. That said, I understand why you'd still want to give the credit - so, upvote. It's still close to the same rep, and to be fair it's not a *complete* answer, anyway.